# Participial Phrase

Tags: grammar, participial-adjectives, non-restrictive

> At Overnight Prints, you'll get the highest quality printing, using Eco-friendly materials and methods, delivered to you on time.

1. "*using Eco-Friendly materials*", does it modify the noun "Overnight Prints", or is it non-essential information of an earlier word, which is quality printing?
2. "*delivered to you on time*", is this phrase referring to the subject "*At Overnight Prints?*"

Comment: Your text is easily understood, but *syntactically* it's not really valid. There's no verb for the adverbial element *using Eco-friendly materials and methods* to modify. To fix that,you'd need to precede it by something like ***carried out** using Eco-friendly...* So don't get too hung up on the syntactic deconstruction.

Comment: I'd say the _using_ phrase is a supplement, a non-modifier providing supplementary non-integrated content. The past-participial clause "delivered to you on time" modifies "highest quality printing".

Comment: @FumbleFingers why can't "using Eco-friendly materials and methods" be considered as a participial phrase that modified "highest quality printing"?

Comment: @JavaLatte: Erm... because "printing" is a noun, which can only be *adjectivally* modified, whereas "using Eco-tech" is an *adverbial* element? All I know is it doesn't look "strictly correct" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In  "Mary saw Peter using Henry's penknife", "using Henry's penknife" is a participial phrase that modifies Peter. it's functioning adjectivally.

Comment: @JavaLatte "Mary saw [Peter using Henry's penknife]": I would say "Peter" is the subject of the "using" clause. "Peter using Henry's penknife is what I saw", not "who I saw".

Comment: @JavaLatte: I'm not convinced ***Peter using a penknife*** is syntactically comparable to ***printing using Eco-tech***. You can treat the former as a noun phrase - something that you ***saw***, but ***I saw printing using Eco-tech*** doesn't parse naturally for me.

Comment: Yep, "printing" is a bog-standard noun, and whatever the "*using...*" phrase modifies has to be inferred by the reader, but it's almost certainly a verb for the printing action.

Comment: @gotube I agree that printing is a noun. Consider this sentence: "The writing of new textbooks using the 2006 curriculum was staggered"  "using the 2006 curriculum" is a participle phrase that modifies "textbooks", not "writing".